# How do I query if a database schema exists

Tags: sql-server-2005, schema

As part of our build process we run a database update script as we deploy code to 4 different environments. Further, since the same query will get added to until we drop a release into production it *has* to be able to run multiple times on a given database.  Like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[Table]'))
BEGIN
  CREATE TABLE [Table]
  (...)
END
```

Currently I have a create schema statement in the deployment/build script.  Where do I query for the existence of a schema?

Comment: Please consider changing the accepted answer. It's not possible that the answer you accepted actually worked for you as written.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Are you looking for [sys.schemas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176011.aspx)?

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'jim')
BEGIN
EXEC('CREATE SCHEMA jim')
END
```

Note that the `CREATE SCHEMA` must be run in its own batch (per [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/521271/2688))

Comment: Darn... in the time it took me to edit the post to make it more readable... you fixed my problem.  Thanks mucho!

Comment: this doesn't work in SQL 2008 because the CREATE SCHEMA needs to be the first statement in a batch, see the vfilby post for a workaround

Comment: You could use 'Select 1 from sys.schemas' to improve the performance.

Comment: @vijaysylvester No, this is a myth. SQL Server optimizes away the column list so it doesn't matter what you put there. Completely ignored. Want proof? Put `SELECT 1/0...`

Comment: And yes, the other, higher-voted answer should be the one that is accepted. This doesn't work as written.

Comment: I've updated this answer to not be incorrect (i.e. to use the script from below http://stackoverflow.com/a/521271/2688)

Comment: While * vs 1 vs 1/0 may not make any performance difference there is a case where it does make a difference.  From a security standpoint, all 3 choices require you to have access to all columns while naming a specific column causes only columns actually named in the query to be checked.  So 'select col-with-access...' succeeds while 'select 1 ...' won't if any column of any table in the query is denied.

Answer (score 170):

@bdukes is right on the money for determining if the schema exists, but the statement above won't work in SQL Server 2005. `CREATE SCHEMA <name>` needs to run in its own batch.  A work around is to execute the `CREATE SCHEMA` statement in an exec.

Here is what I used in my build scripts:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = '<name>')
BEGIN
    -- The schema must be run in its own batch!
    EXEC( 'CREATE SCHEMA <name>' );
END
```

Comment: works like a charm! this even lets me put my print statements and everything.

Answer (score 5):

This is old so I feel compelled to add: For SQL SERVER 2008+ These all work (for the select part), then use `EXECUTE('CREATE SCHEMA <name>')` to actually create it on negative results.

```
DECLARE @schemaName sysname = 'myfunschema';
-- shortest
If EXISTS (SELECT 1 WHERE SCHEMA_ID(@schemaName) IS NOT NULL)
PRINT 'YEA'
ELSE
PRINT 'NOPE'

SELECT DB_NAME() AS dbname WHERE SCHEMA_ID(@schemaName) IS NOT NULL -- nothing returned if not there

IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  top 1 *
                FROM    sys.schemas
                WHERE   name = @schemaName )
PRINT 'WOOPS MISSING'
ELSE
PRINT 'Has Schema'

SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID(@schemaName)) AS SchemaName1 -- null if not there otherwise schema name returned

SELECT SCHEMA_ID(@schemaName) AS SchemaID1-- null if not there otherwise schema id returned


IF EXISTS (
    SELECT sd.SchemaExists 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            CASE 
                WHEN SCHEMA_ID(@schemaName) IS NULL THEN 0
                WHEN SCHEMA_ID(@schemaName) IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                ELSE 0 
            END AS SchemaExists
    ) AS sd
    WHERE sd.SchemaExists = 1
)
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Got it';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Schema Missing';
END
```

Comment: `IF schema_id ('MySchemaName') IS NULL` works well, and seems a bit more convenient than the accepted answer.

Comment: Agree @BradC. For those, who gets exception: IF SCHEMA_ID('out') IS NULL EXEC('CREATE SCHEMA [out] AUTHORIZATION [out]');

Answer (score 2):

If the layout of components allows it, this works too.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'myschema') SET NOEXEC ON 
go
CREATE SCHEMA myschema
GO 
SET NOEXEC OFF -- if any further processing is needed.
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to be *extra* "defensive", the following version generates a Type conversion error to account for the possibility (however unlikely) of > 1 matching `Schema`'s similar to how validation code often intentionally Throw Exception's because I believe it's good to and I believe it's "'best practice'" to account for all possible return results however unlikely and even if it's just to generate a fatal exception because the known effects of stopping processing is usually better than unknown cascading effects of un-trapped errors.  Because it's highly unlikely, I didn't think it's worth the trouble of a separate `Count` check + `Throw` or `Try`-`Catch`-`Throw` to generate a more user-friendly fatal error but still fatal error nonetheless.

SS 2005-:

```
declare @HasSchemaX bit
set @HasSchemaX = case (select count(1) from sys.schemas where lower(name) = lower('SchemaX')) when 1 then 1 when 0 then 0 else 'ERROR' end
```

SS 2008+:

```
declare @HasSchemaX bit = case (select count(1) from sys.schemas where lower(name) = lower('SchemaX')) when 1 then 1 when 0 then 0 else 'ERROR' end
```

Then:

```
if @HasSchemaX = 1
begin
   ...
end -- if @HasSchemaX = 1
```

Comment: I suppose it's possible to have more than one matching schema when you use a case sensitive collation, but your "error handling" will result in the following error: *Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ERROR' to data type int.*

Comment: @Stijn: That's "By Design" similar to how validation code often intentionally `Throw` `Exception`'s.  Like you said, it's not "'likely'" to happen, so IMHO, it wasn't worth a whole `Try`-`Catch` or separate `Count` check to generate a more user-friendly fatal error, but regardless, I would likely want a fatal error.  I believe in and I believe it's "'best practice'" to account for all possible return results however unlikely and even if it's just to generate a fatal exception because the known effects of stopping processing is usually better than unknown cascading effects of un-trapped errors.

Comment: That all sounds fine, I wasn't sure whether it was intentional :) Your answer could benefit from some additional explanation, like you just gave in your comment.

Comment: @Stijn: My pet peeve is the common not-so "'best practice'" of not checking if a `Select`, `Insert`, `Update` or `Delete` Statement returned / affected more *or* less than the expected # of Rows however unlikely.  Even if there is(are) `Unique` `Index`'es currently ensuring the expected #
 (i.e. 1) of Rows to be returned / affected, that could change (accidentally or (short-sightedly) "'intentionally'") in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP (1) 1 FROM [sys].[schemas] WHERE [name] = 'Person')
BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE SCHEMA [Person]')
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP (1) 1 FROM [sys].[tables] AS T
               INNER JOIN [sys].[schemas] AS S ON S.schema_id = T.schema_id
               WHERE T.[name] = 'Guests' AND S.[name] = 'Person')
BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE TABLE [Person].[Guests]
           (
                [GuestId] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
                [Forename] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                [Surname] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                [Email] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                [BirthDate] DATETIME2 NULL,
                CONSTRAINT [PK_Guests_GuestId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([GuestId]),
                CONSTRAINT [UX_Guests_Email] UNIQUE([Email])
           )')
END
```

NOTICE: `CREATE SCHEMA` AND `CREATE TABLE` NEED COMPLETLY SEPARATED BATCH TO EXECUTE

TO MORE DESCRIPTION VISIT MICROSOFT DOCS WEBSITE :)

Comment: Putting the create table in it's own batch isn't necessary when tested on Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   May 12 2022 and using SSMS v18

Answer (score 0):

As of SQL Server 2005 version 9.0 you can use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA view to check if the schema exists:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
SELECT  SCHEMA_NAME
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
WHERE   SCHEMA_NAME =  '<schema name>' )
 
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql N'CREATE SCHEMA <schema name>'  
END
GO
```

INFORMATION_SCHEMA views are the ISO standard and are generally preferable; these were adopted to make the syntax more consistent across different SQL database platforms.

Note that the CREATE SCHEMA must be run in its own batch